# Cassandra Time series modelling for events usecase

Tags: cassandra, hbase, time-series, distributed-system, nosql

I am trying to model my time series events with C* .
However , I am not every sure on the model if it is the most efficient because of the use cases I have.

```
CREATE TABLE events_by_hour (
   event_time timestamp,
   date_hour text,
   customer_id text,
   PRIMARY KEY ((customer_id,date_hour),event_time)
); // I dont want to keep data older then 2 weeks m so every column will have a ttl of 2 weeks+delta
```

**Also , There will be another column family to track row keys because of the use case below:**

```
CREATE TABLE customer_rowKeys (
       date_hour text,
       customer_id text,
       PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
    ); // This column family will also have a ttl of 2 weeks
```

My use case is I would want events from time t1 to t2 but only 100 at a time. In the next call I would want subsequent 100 and so on. I can make use of Slice query on columns and keep passing the offset in subsequent call(something like pagination). Now, The problem I see with this is , as each row contains an hour of data, for some customers the row could be very wide and for some it could be skinny . Now if the time difference between t1 to t2 is a week. How do I proceed. Also , each customer will not have data for every hour , so there will be holes ? **The worst case assume every hour had only 1 event , I will end up making 100 calls.**

How can the above use case be optimally handled in Cassandra ?

Comment: Cassandra rows are not like RDBMS rows, which are (in some implementations) stored as fixed width records. It does not matter if dome rows are skinny and some are fat.

Comment: @Raedwald If you will read the problem again . This is not what I am worried about. The problem is mentioned in bold characters in last line which will occur sue to skinny rows which is why I am looking for a better model.

Comment: The model is a very good one. Per your mention though if its not used often it can make reads very inefficient in some use cases.  An approach I've used is to have the date_hour be a iso 8601 timestamp, and always start with day range and dynamically drop down to hourly/half/15 min based on load.  When reading you can use a merged iterator type approach to read from multiple events_by_hour partitions at a time incase theres some overlap between the different time ranges. This gets pretty tricky but its probably one of the best approaches I have seen to avoid too wide of rows vs too many reads.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink Do you have any blog post or any useful link to determine dynamic row keys in a distributed environment. I mean If multiple ingesters are writing to cassandra one might end up creating hour based key and one day based. How to prevent that ? Do you have a central controller for determining keys ?

Comment: Its where things gets a little complex. Basically you expect that different ingesters may be using different periods. So you start reading from both the day and hour periods at the closest to your start time. Since the clustering index will skip the day periods columns until the ones your expecting it will only grab the ones you care about.You can use something like Guava's merged iterator to walk both of those two partitions (or three) to resolve it. As you reach the end of one of the periods partition (ie the hour partition) you add the next hours partition to your merged iterator and repeat